# Java multi-clients server socket getting errors

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I've tried making a simple server to accept multiple sockets & then let them input and receive an output.

But it seems like I am doing it wrong as I am getting many errors.
Is the way I am trying to do that bad? How can I do that in a better way?

I dont understand why do I get these errors:

```
Starting up..
Trying to listen...
Server is successfully running on port 43594
New connection: /127.0.0.1:60639
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Client.getInputStream(Client.java:29)
    at ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:19)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Client.getInputStream(Client.java:29)
    at ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:19)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Client.getInputStream(Client.java:29)
    at ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:19)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Client.getInputStream(Client.java:29)
    at ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:19)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Client.getInputStream(Client.java:29)
    at ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:19)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Client.getInputStream(Client.java:29)
    at ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:19)
```

And many many more lines of errors. Its basically looping the same error over and over, but why?

I've commented the code so you can see what i've tried to do and maybe fix the way I do that.

```
public class Server {

    private int port = 43594;

    public void listen() {
        System.out.println("Trying to listen...");
        try {
            final ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            // Create new thread to handle clients I/O
            ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler(server);
            // START it
            handler.start();
            System.out.println("Server is successfully running on port " + port);
            while (true) {
                // New connection found create a new Client object
                Client cl = new Client(server.accept());
                cl.setup();
                // add it to clietns list in the I/O handler
                handler.clients.add(cl);
            }           
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start up
        System.out.println("Starting up..");

        // server instance
        final Server server = new Server();

        // create a new thread for server
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // listen for new connections
                server.listen();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

public class ClientHandler extends Thread {

    private Thread handler;
    public ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>(); // client list
    private ServerSocket server;

    public ClientHandler(ServerSocket s) {
        server = s;
    }

    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            // Loop every time through every client and see if he has wrote
            // anything to do server. I am 100% sure this is wrong, how can I do this
            // without using multithreads (thread per client)?
            for (Client c : this.clients) {
                if (c.getInputStream() != null) {
                    // found input, return a message.
                    c.sendMessage("hey client");
                }
            }
            try {
                // sleep for 100ms
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Client {

    private Socket socket;
    private int clientId;
    private BufferedReader inStream;
    private PrintWriter outStream;
    private boolean socketAlive = true;

    public Client(Socket sock) {
        this.socket = sock;
    }

    public void setup() {
        setInputOutputStream();
        System.out.println("New connection: " + this.getIpAddress());
        this.sendMessage("Successfully connected!");
    }


    public String getInputStream() {
        String toReturn = "";
        try {
            toReturn = this.inStream.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return toReturn;
    }

    private void setInputOutputStream() {
        try {
            inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream())); 
            outStream = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String s) {
        this.outStream.println(s);
        this.outStream.flush();
    }

    public String getIpAddress() {
        return this.socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
    }
}
```

And not sure if it will be useful, this is the client:

```
public class TestClient {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws UnknownHostException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Client started");
            Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 43594);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input;
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

            input = scanner.nextLine();

            if (input != null) {
                out.print(input);
            }
            if (reader.toString() != null) {
                System.out.println(reader.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Client error");
        }

    }

}
```

*Why is the connection keeps getting reset?*

Answer (score 0):

The client **has no loop or delay**, so it would just immediately quit as soon as it sent data. When a program quits, the operating system always closes all of its network connections!

Also, I don't think this does what you want it to do: `System.out.println(reader.toString());`. Check the output of the client!

Answer (score 0):

You are writing things from the server that you aren't reading at the client. Instead the client just exits after the print. 'reader.toString() doesn't do any I/O. You need to call a read method.